# Issue with Custom Prompt with an agent Using LangChain and GPT-4

Tags: python, pandas, langchain

I'm working on a project using LangChain to create an agent that can answer questions based on some pandas DataFrames. I'm using a GPT-4 model for this. I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to pass a custom prompt template into the agent but it doesn't seem to be taking it into account.

I can see the chain of thought in LangSmith, it's the basic template of the agent: ```You are working with 4 pandas dataframes in Python named df1, df2, etc. This is the result of `print(df.head())` for each dataframe:````

However, the custom `PROMPT` doesn't seem to be applied when running queries. Has anyone encountered this issue or knows how to properly set a custom prompt?

The prompt I would like to pass explain that I want the result in another language, and to define what kind of files are in the Json.

I send this code to a Streamlit app after that.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import create_pandas_dataframe_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType
from langsmith import Client
from langchain.smith import RunEvalConfig, run_on_dataset

# define my dataframes
df1 = ...
df2 = ...

PROMPT = """
# Custom prompt 
...
"""

llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-4")

template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(PROMPT)

agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
    llm,
    [df1, df2],
    agent_type=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
    prompt_template=template,  # This line is supposed to set the prompt
    verbose=True,
    max_iterations=5,
    early_stopping_method='generate',
)

from langsmith import Client
client = Client()
def send_feedback(run_id, score):
    client.create_feedback(run_id, "user_score", score=score)

query_text = st.text_input("Ask your question:", placeholder = "Example")

result = None
with st.form('myform', clear_on_submit=True):
    submitted = st.form_submit_button('Submit')
    if submitted:
        with st.spinner('Searching'):
            response = agent({"input": query_text}, include_run_info=True)
            result = response["output"]
            run_id = response["__run"].run_id
if result is not None:
    st.info(result)
    col_blank, col_text, col1, col2 = st.columns([10, 2,1,1])
    with col_text:
        st.text("Feedback:")
    with col1:
        st.button("", on_click=send_feedback, args=(run_id, 1))
    with col2:
        st.button("", on_click=send_feedback, args=(run_id, 0))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: add some sample custom prompts and the results you are getting. also, show more code on how are you executing those prompts.

Comment: Hi, I've added some details to my message! Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you manage to solve this if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found:

1. import `from langchain_experimental.agents.agent_toolkits.pandas.prompt import PREFIX`
2. pass the prompt into `PREFIX ="..."`
3. In the agent configuration, add `prefix=PREFIX`

```
    agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
        llm, 
        [df1,df2], 
        agent_type=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
        prefix = PREFIX,
        verbose=True, 
        max_iterations=5,
        early_stopping_method='generate',
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
agent1 = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
llm,
[df1, df2],
agent_type=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
verbose=True,
max_iterations=5,
early_stopping_method='generate',
)

agent1.agent.llm_chain.prompt.template = template # This line is supposed to set the prompt
```